# Date conversion and manipulation in javascript with Arabic months

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion

I want to change an arabic long-form date, i.e.

```
الخميس 26 فبراير 2015

(Thursday 26th February, 2015)
```

into a standard date using standard Javascript in order to manipulate the date (add a day), then display via `Date.toLocaleDateString()` to convert it back, making

```
2015 الخميس 27 فبراير

(Friday 27th February, 2015)
```

Is this a case of picking the date string apart, interpreting the arabic text as a month number and creating a new Date() given the numbers, or is there a prototype that converts an arabic date string into a javascript date? What language and optional parameters need to be used for `Date.toLocaleDateString()` to produce the same format of arabic date, as using 'ar' the numbers are returned in eastern arabic, as opposed to the required western numerals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var months = ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "إبريل", "مايو", "يونيو",
              "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"];

var days =["اﻷحد","اﻷثنين","الثلاثاء","اﻷربعاء","الخميس","الجمعة","السبت"];

var date = new Date();

console.log("The current month is " + months[date.getMonth()]);
console.log("The current day is " + days[date.getDay()]);
```

Comment: While this doesn't provide the answer per se, it does provide me with enough information to check which month/day is present via a for loop for each array performing an indexOf on the date string, determining the value and generating the date in a workable format. It also suggests that the `Date.toLocaleDateString()` isn't useful in this instance.