# How to format date into Arabic with English numerals for date and year in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, arabic

I want the date to be formatted in the following format:

> date: 2016-12-04 into الأحد، 4 ديسمبر، 2016

But I'm getting the following. The numbers are converted to Arabic numerals. I want the date and year in English numerals:

> الأحد، ٤ ديسمبر، ٢٠١٦

I have used the following code to format the date to Arabic.

```
var date = new Date('2016-12-04');
options = {
           weekday: 'long',
           year: 'numeric',
           month: 'short',
           day: 'numeric',
          };
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString('ar-SA', options);
alert(dateString);
```

Comment: Hope my answer below answers your question?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution [Date conversion and manipulation in javascript with Arabic months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694214/date-conversion-and-manipulation-in-javascript-with-arabic-months)

My modified code to get my desired output is as follows.

```js
var date = new Date('2016-12-04');
var months = ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "إبريل", "مايو", "يونيو",
  "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"
];
var days = ["اﻷحد", "اﻷثنين", "الثلاثاء", "اﻷربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت"];
var delDateString = days[date.getDay()] + ', ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.getFullYear();

console.log(delDateString); // Outputs اﻷحد, 4 ديسمبر, 2016
```

Comment: Note that `new Date('2016-12-04')` will parse the string as UTC, but your *get* methods are using local. Users in a timezone west of Greenwich will see a date for the previous day.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this Locales to specify numbering system.

```
let date = newDate.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG-u-nu-latn',{weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});
```

also check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) MDN link to know more about it

Comment: Thank you so much ( Jazak Allah khairan ).

Answer (score 3):

A better (safer) way to get the Hijri (Islamic) date **in English Numerals (Western-Arabic Numbers)** in javascript is **NOT to use a specific country locale** like "ar-SA" or "ar-TN" or "ar-EG"; but use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with the following `Locale options`:

1. The **numbering system** (**nu**) set to `latn` (i.e. Western-Arabic Numbers), and
2. **Calendar type** (**ca**) set to `islamic`, and
3. The **language locale** to `ar`

The Locale options can be passed as an **array** for multiple options: `["ar-u-ca-islamic","ar-u-nu-latn"]`

or as one string : `"ar-u-ca-islamic-nu-latn"`

Here is an example code that will print today's Hijri (Islamic) date with Western-Arabic Numbers (English Numerals):

I have also included a table to give the **list of all Arabic "ar" locales** and the default outputs to see the difference between them with regards to the name of the months and the default number system.

```js
let options = {day: 'numeric', month: 'long',weekday:'long',year:'numeric'};

// 1st method
let locales = ["ar-u-ca-islamic","ar-u-nu-latn"];
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locales, options).format(Date.now()));

// 2nd method
locales = "ar-u-ca-islamic-nu-latn";
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locales, options).format(Date.now()));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the current hijri date in javascript, we can use `Intl.DateTimeFormat`

To get the arabic display :

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-TN-u-ca-islamic', {day: 'numeric', month: 'long',weekday: 'long',year : 'numeric'}).format(Date.now());
```

the expected output :

```
السبت، 4 صفر 1443 هـ
```

https://medium.com/@Saf_Bes/get-today-hijri-date-in-javascript-90855d3cd45b

Comment: This uses the Arabic locale for Tunisia to get a western-Arabic number (English Numerals) which is dangerous because the locale spec may change.

Comment: See alternative solution above for Islamic date in English Numerals.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'ar-MA' (for Morocco) instead of 'ar-SA'.

Comment: Should be a comment

Comment: Why should it be a comment? It's a valid answer:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS28S_3.0.0/com.ibm.help.forms.doc/locale_spec/i_xfdl_r_formats_ar_MA.html

Comment: I tried the **ar_MA** locale, it showing the Arabic numeral in Google Chrome V48. But the same worked in Firefox.
https://jsfiddle.net/daj2jm3p/3/